# Objects disappear once celery task finishes

Tags: django, celery

I have a celery task that creates a bunch of objects from uploaded data in a view. The objects exist whilst the task is running and then when it finishes, the objects are no longer in the database. I know this because I opened a separate django shell and while the task is running I can `get` the items added, but as soon as it finishes they are no longer there. Any ideas?

My task:

```
@task
def upload_data_things(session):
    ... #munging data
    for line in munged_data:
        new_thing = thing.objects.update_or_create(**kwargs, default=other_kwargs)
```

And the view:
    def upload_things(request, session_pk):
        session = get_object_or_404(models.UploadSession, pk=session_pk)
        upload_data_things.delay(session)
        return HttpResponse(status=201)

Comment: Have you manually queried for the data in django shell? If it's writing to the same database, there's no reason that the data is gone.

Comment: That's what I meant above. The data is gone, I query it, it's there, a few seconds later when the task finishes it goes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a long shot, but does your object have a foreign key with another object that gets deleted in the same celery task?

I had a similar issue where the foreign key relationship had cascade on delete which was causing my object to be created, then deleted once I deleted the referenced object.

Comment: This is so long ago I can't remember now, but this must be the solution to this.